# Loop for plotting multiple graph

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe with 1104 rows and 2 columns

```
a<-rep(1998:2013,times=69)
b<-rnorm(1104)
data<-data.frame(a,b)
```

What I am trying to do is plot the first 48 rows in the following fashion:

```
plot(data$b[1:16] ~ data$a[1:16],col="red")
points(data$b[17:32] ~ data$a[17:32],col="green")
points(data$b[33:48] ~ data$a[33:48],col="blue")
```

This will give me a graph with three sets of data on it. Then I want to repeat this for the next set of 48 rows, something like this:

```
plot(data$b[49:64] ~ data$a[1:16])
points(data$b[65:80] ~ data$a[65:80])
points(data$b[81:96] ~ data$a[81:96])
```

And I want to keep repeating it till the 1104th row

```
plot(data$b[1057:1072] ~ data$a[1057:1072])
points(data$b[1073:1088] ~ data$a[1073:1088])
points(data$b[1089:1104] ~ data$a[1089:1104])
```

Is there any way I can put this in a loop? This implies that I will have 23 plots.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code is rather unclear what you want, considering you are limiting the length of your x-axis in your initial plot to `data$a[1:16]`, where you wanting to stack all of the data points? Do you have an image of a desired output (or something similar)? Also your limits access 2 different datasets, is that intentional (min of a, max of b)?

Comment: I removed that bit. It wasn't necessary. Thanks

Comment: Can you show, how one plot looks like? your `points` are outside of plot and they are not being plotted. What is the desired output?

Comment: Ah! sorry. I fail miserably in creating artificial data. Now I have fixed my question. This should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some column in initial dataset.

```
set.seed(1)
a<-rep(1998:2013,times=69)
b<-rnorm(1104)
set<-rep(1:23,each=48)
col<-rep(c("red","green", "blue"),each=16, times=23)
data<-data.frame(a,b, set, col)
```

I like to work with ggplot, but you use base if you want

```
library(ggplot2)

pdf("multplot.pdf")

for (x in 1:23){
  #subset data based on set
  df.s<-subset(data, set==x)
  g<-ggplot(df.s, aes(x=a,y=b, color=col))+geom_point()
  print(g)

}
dev.off()
```

in base R

```
pdf("multplot2.pdf")

for (x in 1:23){

  df.s<-subset(data, set==x)
  #the `col` column is not used
  plot(df.s$b[1:16] ~ df.s$a[1:16],col="red")
  points(df.s$b[17:32] ~ df.s$a[17:32],col="green")
  points(df.s$b[33:48] ~ df.s$a[33:48],col="blue")

}
dev.off()
```